# How does LaTeX find package files?

Tags: installing, texlive, linux

On a fresh install of TeXlive on a Linux box (Linux Mint 11) I get the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `scalefnt.sty' not found.
```

But the file is there:

```
$ find /usr/ -name 'scalefnt.sty'  -print
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty
```

Why `pdflatex` did not find it?
Is it a bug in the TeXLive installation process?

Until now I have solved this problem by adding lines like this one :

```
export TEXINPUTS=$TEXINPUTS:/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/carlisle/
```

in my `.bashrc` file.
Now I have 20+ such lines in my `.bashrc`. 
There must be a better way to solve this problem.

-- Update --
Running `texhash` did not solve the problem.

```
$ sudo texhash
[sudo] password :
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

I think the `ls-R` file in `/usr/local/share/` was created by `texhash`. It is empty. I found in the `kpathsea` doc how to log : `export TEXMFLOG=/tmp/texmf.log`. After running `pdflatex` I get in the log :

```
$ cat /tmp/texmf.log 
1309254390 /var/lib/texmf/ls-R
1309254390 /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf/ls-R
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/ls-R
1309254390 /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/letter.cls
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/letter.cls
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/frenchb.ldf
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/frenchb.ldf
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/frenchb.cfg
1309254390 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/frenchb.cfg
```

In the texlive setup I use, the files `/usr/share/texmf/ls-R` and `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/ls-R` are links to `/var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN` and `/var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE` respectively.

I don't understand why it does not work since the style file is in one of the ls-R files:

```
$ grep scalefnt.sty /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE
scalefnt.sty
```

This looks like a bug in the texlive package installation process (in Linux Mint/Ubuntu).

Comment: You definitely shouldn't need all those modifications to $TEXINPUTS.  Have you tried running `mktexlsr` (texhash)?  You should be able to do `sudo texhash` or `sudo mktexlsr` to rebuild the list of files.  Does that solve the problem?

Comment: I met the same problem. But I occasionally found it in my case that I have to change the file permissions for .sty files.
This could be the answer.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I have just run into what looks like the same problem after doing a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 and then installing texlive via apt-get. In my case it cannot find 'article.cls' but on running 'sudo latex test.tex' it works

Answer (score 21):

Modern TeX distributions use [kpathsea library](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kpathsea) to find the files.

If your TeX Live cannot find the file, try to run `texhash` to refresh the file name database. On Linux / Mac, run `sudo texhash`.

Comment: Thanks to Alan & Leo. I tried both sudo texhash and sudo mktexlsr. I get the following output: mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
But I continue to get the same error.

Comment: @Davy_Crockett: It seems that you installed two TeX Live distributions: one is from Linux source (at `/usr/share/`), the other one is from TUG (at `/usr/local/share/`). You don't have `scalefnt.sty` in the TUG one (`usr/local/share/...`). Or maybe you wrongly installed TeX Live.

Comment: I updated the question because it did not fit in a comment.

Comment: `sudo texhash` did the trick for me. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Boris: I converted your answer to a comment. Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank Leo by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers.

Answer (score 1):

What happened to me was: in Ubuntu 11.10 I defined the environment variable TEXMFCN to point at my home directory

> $TEXMFCNF=$HOME/texmf/web2c
>
> export TEXMFCNF

For some reason, after the upgrade to 14.04, the bash gave a different interpretation to my setting: to search the latex packages *only* in my home directory. So, commenting that line in .bashrc

> # $TEXMFCNF=$HOME/texmf/web2c
>
> # export TEXMFCNF

worked out for me. Defining the variable by including the paths to all the existing files texmf.cfn

> $TEXMFCNF=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:$HOME/texmf/web2c
>
> export TEXMFCNF

also works.