# Latex on Linux: Path problem after new install of TeX Live

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, paths

**UPDATE:** between the suggestions made in comments, and Andrew Stacey's patient walkthrough/diagnostic, the problem was eventually solved by correcting a faulty environment variable in the bashrc. It's not entirely clear to me if this was the only problem all along, since I recall things not working even with a vanilla bashrc, but it does seem that the eventual problem lay in my ineptitude with paths rather than some exotic issue with permissions.

---

This may well be a duplicate of something that's already been covered here -- in fact it seems close to the problem described at "[How does LaTeX find package files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/how-does-latex-find-package-files)" -- so I hope this is not too trivial.

I have just had to do a clean install (Ubuntu 12.04 if that makes a difference) on my desktop and after restoring files from my backup, set about reinstalling *texlive* by the naive *apt-get* method. Now I find *latex test.tex* is met with

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
>   entering extended mode
>   (./test.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
>   Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.

while *sudo latex test.tex* works fine. I have tried restoring the bashrc to the one that was working before, but to no avail. Similarly, the advice suggested at answers to [the question mentioned above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/how-does-latex-find-package-files)
 doesn't seem to fix things; running *texhash* makes no difference, and purging and reinstalling also hasn't helped.

I guess I could add export lines to bashrc but since this was never necessary in any previous installation I had of TeXLive, I would like to know what I've done wrong this time.

Comment: I suggest install the Debian TeXLive 2009 from Ubuntu software center/synaptic manager/sudo temporarily. It will be a clean install( no need to tinker with .bashrc etc..). In the [coming July/Aug](http://tug.org/texlive/) install TeXLive 2013. Incase you are interested to do [pretest TeXLive 2013](http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html). TeXLive 2012 is frozen now.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich article.cls` return?  If it doesn't find anything, or points to the wrong place, that's, well, not good.  It is possible that you have reinstalled from your backup an old copy of `texmf.cnf`, which is causing some havok.  That would be what I looked into first.

Comment: @jon It returns nothing. *sudo kpsewhich article.cls* returns */usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls* - I'm afraid I'm puzzled as to how to intepret this

Comment: @texenthusiast that doesn't help - after all, the methods you describe are more or less the same as doing a apt-get purge+autoremove+clean+install

Comment: [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95483/15717) and reinstall texlive full 2009 `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Comment: I have never encountered this before, so I hope someone else will jump in with a solution.  Does `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF` only work with `sudo` as well?  That sounds like a permission problem ... or maybe(?) an environment (`env`) problem.

Comment: @YemonChoi: Did you try a `texhash` (without sudo)?

Comment: @jon Late response - I have been away from the offending desktop for the last month: kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF (without sudo) returns {/home/yemon/.texmf-config,/home/yemon/.texmf-var,/home/yemon/texmf,/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf-texlive}

Comment: Well, that looks (from what I remember) how it should given an install from the Debian/Ubuntu repositories.  Your problem is very odd.  Is there more than one user on this computer?  It seems like there is some confusion over permissions..?

Answer (score 7):

This looks very much like a permissions problem.  I've encountered this when I've done an installation using `tlmgr`, though I'm surprised at its rearing its ugly head when installation is done using `apt-get`.

#### The Likely Problem

At some point in the installation, files were installed that were only usable by the `root` account.  That is, ordinary users do not have *permission* to read the necessary files for `latex` to work.

In brief, every file and directory on a UNIX system has three sets of three permissions (sort of).  The three sets are: `owner`, `group`, `world` and the three permissions are `read`, `write`, `execute`.  In order to use a file or directory you have to have sufficient permissions to carry out the activity.  Which permissions apply depend on your relationship to the file (or directory) in question.  For the files installed in a TeXLive installation, the most likely situation is that you do not own the files (`root` does) nor are you in the same group as the files (probably something like `admin`) so the `world` permissions apply to you.  When you do `ls -l <file name>` then the first block looks something like `-rw-r--r--`.  It is the last three that therefore concern you.  What you need is to have `r--` for ordinary files and `r-x` for directories and executable files.

#### Diagnosing the Problem

To check this hypothesis, you need to find the permissions of (some of) the files.  From the comments, the first thing to try is:

```
ls -l /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
```

With a bit of luck, this will complain:

```
cannot access /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls: Permission denied
```

If so, it's a permissions problem.  (It might be that the message is `cannot open directory` and that the path is only a part of the path given.)

#### Making sure it doesn't happen again

When software is installed, it tries to install it as permissively as possible so that any user can use it.  However, when you create a file in your own directory you *don't* want this behaviour: you want it so that you can use it, but no other user can do so.  Unfortunately, the system can't tell the difference between these two cases and just sees the instruction "Create a file/directory".  Now you can say "Create a file/directory *with these permissions*" but then that's hard for a user to override if they want to do a local installation.  So what happens is the request is "Create a file/directory and *suggest* these permissions".  The "suggestion" is then matched against something called the `umask` to get the real permissions.  You can think of the `umask` as a polariser: it only allows certain permissions to get through.

Permissions are stored as octal numbers, with 4 = read, 2 = write, 1 = executable.  An installer might say "This is an executable file, I suggest permissions 755" meaning everyone can read and execute it, and the owner can write to it.  This is then checked against the `umask` to see which of these permissions can be set.  A common user `umask` is 077.  This allows through all user permissions but none of the others so the resulting file permissions are 700.  On the other hand, the standard `umask` for a system installation is `022`.  This guards against files being writeable by non-owners but otherwise lets everything else through.  Then the 755 would work.

What is likely to have happened here is that the `umask` in effect was 077 instead of 022.  This can sometimes happen when using `sudo` since then the `umask` is not changed from its user setting.  To avoid this happening again, the command `umask 022` changes the `umask` to 022 (`umask` by itself displays the current setting) so this can be done before the installation, and then reset afterwards.

(However, as I said, I'm a little surprised at this happening with `apt-get` since I would expect that to be `umask`-savvy and sort itself out.  `tlmgr` does *not*, though.)

#### Fixing Things Afterwards

Deleting and reinstalling is one option, but given the size of TeXLive it's a bit of a sledgehammer.  A little more refined is fixing the permissions.

The first thing to do is work out where the problem starts.  To do that, start with the `article.cls` path that you have and find out where you first lose permission:

```
ls -l /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
ls -ld /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base
ls -ld /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex
ls -ld /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex
ls -ld /usr/share/texmf-texlive
ls -ld /usr/share
```

(If you get to the bottom one and *still* have problems, then you have ***big*** problems.)

Most likely, it is `/usr/share/texmf-texlive`.  Next is to get a sense of the scale of the problem:

```
sudo find /usr/share/texmf-texlive -not -perm -004
```

This gives you a list of all the files and folders below `texmf-texlive` which are not world-readable.  It might just be that it is only the top directory that has the wrong permissions, if so then do the following:

1. Give a small "whoop" of joy
2. `sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/texmf-texlive`

If the list is very short, you can do something similar to the above on each of the files/directories.  The rules are that the permission to give is whatever the owner has *without* the writeable one.  `chmod` can take "symbolic" permissions so you don't have to remember the octal notation (symbolic is actually better here as the syntax for *adding* permissions is simple).  In short:

1. Do `sudo ls -l <filename>`
2. Examine the first bit, it will start with one of `drwx`, `-rwx`, or `-rw-`
3. If one of the first two, do `sudo chmod go+rx <filename>`
4. If the last one, do `sudo chmod go+r <filename>`

If the list is quite long, going through each one is a pain.  Fortunately, `find` can iterate through the list of files and execute a command on each one.  We have to do it twice to fix the two situations.

First, we go through and add the `read` bit to all files and folders.

```
sudo find /usr/share/texmf-texlive -not -perm -004 -exec chmod go+r {} ';'
```

Then, we go through and add the `execute` bit to all executable files and all folders.

```
sudo find /usr/share/texmf-texlive -perm +100 -not -perm -001 -exec chmod go+x {} ';'
```

At this point, everything should have the right permissions.

#### Caveat

There is a faint chance that there are some files which aren't meant to be world readable in the TeXLive tree, or executable files which aren't meant to be executable by anyone but root.  However, I doubt that.

(Unfortunately, as I can't guarantee that my last TL installation didn't need this permission fix, I can't trust that the permissions in my installation are all as they were intended so I can't test this myself.)

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough walkthrough. (How does one get a quote environment in comments?) Unfortunately **ls -l /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls** doesn't return a permissions error but gives me **-rw-r--r--** (owner and group are root)

Comment: to confirm: kpsewhich article.cls gives nothing?  Compare **which latex** for you and root.

Comment: And try **kpsewhich texmf.cnf** for both.

Comment: **which latex** returns **/usr/bin/latex** for both. **kpsewhich texmf.cnf** returns **/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf** for both.

Comment: Trying to track down *some* difference between the user account and the root account!  Try `kpsewhich -show-path .cls`

Comment: Bingo - user account just has my personal TEXINPUTS folders (as set in .bashrc) while root gives loads, including /usr/share/texmf and /usr/share/texmf-texlive

Comment: Does the "Bingo" mean that you've solved it, or just that you're on the right track?  If the former: Great!  If the latter, I would now try removing *all* TeX-related environment variables and see if that works, then add them back one by one to see which one breaks things.

Comment: The latter, I'm afraid. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Having poked in the bashrc I am ashamed to say that I had *forgotten* to adjoin the existing TEXINPUTS to the user-defined ones - the bashrc was copied and pasted from various machines over the years and on some iteration it must have let me get away with this for some reason! Anyway, it is now fixed - not sure if one of the earlier delete and installs also contributed to the resolution, though

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  Now, this question-and-answer is a bit of a mess since my answer wasn't the solution.  It's also possible that given what the problem was, the correct thing to do is close as "too localised".  However, having written out the answer I'm loathe to do that!  What we could do is edit your question and my answer to make them both a bit more generic.  Something on the lines of "I've installed TeX but can't compile any documents, though root can do so.  What can I do?" whereupon my current answer is *one* possibility but environment variables is another which could be added.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same diagnose and same solution as Yemon Choi (and Loop Space) with `TEXINPUTS` being defined in the wrong way. My `.pam_environment` reads

```
TEXINPUTS=.:/home/faan/fnielsen/sty
```

Adding the colon at the end

```
TEXINPUTS=.:/home/faan/fnielsen/sty:
```

corrects the problem.