# amsthm.sty package instalation problem under Linux

Tags: texmaker, linux

Im using Texmaker 3.2 under Linux Mint 13 Maya and I have problem with installing amsthm package. When I typed:

```
\begin{theorem}
some theorem
\end{theorem}
```

I got ! LaTeX Error: Environment theorem undefined. Then I tried

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

but it gives me again the same error. From what I read I'm missing the package amsthm. I read in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449370/latex-error-environment-proof-undefined that I have to install amscls.zip and amsmath.zip files. I followed the steps from here http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex and Im pretty sure that I have the file amsthm.sty in the right directory (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amscls) Howhever my Texmaker cannot find it. (When I type `\usepackage{amsthm}` the editor underlines the word amsthm with red line.) I also used the command **sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra biblatex** and of course this also didn't help. Can anyone tell me what I am missind/doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  When installing did update the tex database via `texhash` or `mktexlsr`?

Comment: amsthm is part of the required latex distribution. If you have LaTeX you have amsthm already (or you have a broken distribution).

Comment: @AndrewSwann I tried and it did not helped :( Now Im reading this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/how-does-latex-find-package-files, hopefully it will help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

do you actually have `\usepackage{amsthm}` in your preamble?

if `amsthm` wasn't installed on your system, *that* would give you an error
(a different one) *much* sooner.

since the error is delayed until you try to *use* a theorem, it sounds like
you just forgot to load the package.

(a minimum non-working example would have made that sort of error obvious
very quickly.  had to use my crystal ball instead, and it's been a bit murky lately.)