# How to use emoji in LaTeX documents? Specifically getting a custom `.sty` working

Tags: packages, compiling, tex-core, uplatex

Following instructions from https://github.com/alecjacobson/coloremoji.sty ;

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/local
cd ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/local
git clone git@github.com:alecjacobson/coloremoji.sty.git
texhash coloremoji.sty
```

Output the following;

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/local
$ texhash coloremoji.sty
texhash: Updating /home/vco/Library/texmf/tex/latex/local/coloremoji.sty/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

However after trying to `\usepackage{coloremoji}` I got the following error;

```
! LaTeX Error: File `coloremoji.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

I'm not sure why this is - it seems to be talking about not finding the file
though. I tried to use this on `./coloremoji.sty/coloremoji.sty` rather than
just the dir, but this didn't work either. Returned the following message;

```
$ texhash ./coloremoji.sty/coloremoji.sty 
texhash: ./coloremoji.sty/coloremoji.sty: not a directory, skipping.
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
```

I'm not sure what I should do in order to get this working.

## edit

tried to run `texhash` with sudo

```
$ ls
coloremoji.sty
vco @ geoHP
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/local
$ sudo texhash coloremoji.sty/
sudo: texhash: command not found
vco @ geoHP
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/local
```

Though it's on the system

```
$ which texhash
/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/texhash
```

## System that I'm using

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken individual *.sty files are not texhash'd, rather you texhash and your system setup determines which directory texhash looks in. If you look in the questions there are a lot of questions regarding where to put the files, and how to deal with errors in texhashing. For instance in your example texhash is skipping directories because you are not root (or have insufficient privilege otherwise) and skipping "coloremoji.sty" because it is not a directory.

Comment: See this Question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/how-does-latex-find-package-files/21729#21729 try `sudo texhash`

Comment: And this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: @AFeldman thanks - but in the first example there were no errors or mention of root, i'll try it now though with sudo thanks

Comment: linux or mac? I think if you specified your computing environment that would help.

Comment: @AFeldman thanks - added system info to post

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `~/Library/texmf` if you are on Ubuntu. You should not have a directory `~/Library` at all (unless you use it for your e-novels or something).

The relevant directory is probably `~/texmf`. Check with

```
kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME
```

Whichever directory is correct, `texhash` is almost certainly irrelevant unless you have altered the defaults. TeX doesn't use a database for your personal tree (TEXMFHOME) - it searches the file system directly. So when you install files there, that's enough. As long as the directory hierarchy is right, TeX will find the file. (And if it doesn't, `texhash` won't help.)

Comment: Finally, a canonical answer regarding 'texhash' and Ubuntu. Nice.