# Including images in custom cls

Tags: graphics, texmf

Let's say I have a custom class which is well recognized by `pdflatex` and in the right directory (texmf).

How could I integrate images (logos in headers) to be printed in each document using the class without copying them each time in the working directory or using absolute path (in order to be platform-independent) ?

I tried to put the images in the same directory of the class but pdflatex says they are not found as if it's searching in the current working directory of the file using the class.

Comment: Did you refresh the texhash? What's the image type? Normally images are also found. Example from TeXLive: ./tex/latex/beamer2thesis contains an image beamer2thesis.jpg. If you add `\includegraphics{beamer2thesis}` the graphic is found. You may also check the package [mwe](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) for included images.

Comment: How could I refresh it ?
The images are pdf.

Comment: This depends on your installation (Miktex, TeXlive...). Please check also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/how-does-latex-find-package-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that indicate the graphics path with the command `\graphicspath{}` using relative path like `./foo/bar/` in the `myclass.cls` eliminate the trouble.