# How does texhash know how where to find package files?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, installing, mac

I am using MacTex 2017 with OS X High Sierra. When I try to compile a .tex file using pdflatex it gets stuck at finding a package `packagename.sty`.

After some searching that I found those packages installed inside the directory

`/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/packagename/packagename.sty`

When I run `sudo texhash` I get

```
texhash: Updating /opt/local/etc/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /opt/local/share/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /opt/local/share/texmf-local/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /opt/local/var/db/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Done.
```

I did not find packagename.sty inside any of the files above.

But if I set the variable TEXINPUTS as,

```
export TEXINPUTS=$TEXINPUTS:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/packagename/
```

Then pdflatex is able to find packagename.sty.

So my question is how do I tell texhash to update the config files to tell pdflatex to find the packages inside the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/<packages>` automatically without having to set the variable TEXINPUTS myself ?

related question : [How does LaTeX find package files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/how-does-latex-find-package-files)

Comment: Something is up with your setup: looks like `root` doesn't have your TL'17 system on the path, but rather MacPorts or similar

Comment: Do you have another TeX distribution installed by MacPorts or Fink? What does `echo $PATH` return when run in Terminal?

Comment: @JosephWright Ok. I recently added MacPorts and Fink on my system.

Comment: @HerbSchulz 'echo $PATH' returns

/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/heroku/bin

Comment: Add the line `export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH` to the bottom of your `.profile` and/or `.bash_profile` found in you HOME folder so that the TeX Live installed by MacTeX is found before the other distributions. MacPortsand Fink play with you PATH variable.