# Do `most` options of tcolorbox still work?

Tags: tcolorbox

In my distribution, the MWE fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

with the error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
(preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
(./bac_a_sable.tex LaTeX2e <2017-04-15    Babel <3.10    and hyphenation
patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbraster.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbraster.code.tex' version '4.13' )
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '4.13'
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '4.13' ))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '4.13' )
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbhooks.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbhooks.code.tex' version '4.13' )
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbtheorems.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbtheorems.code.tex' version '4.13'
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty For
additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbfitting.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbfitting.code.tex' version '4.13' )
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbxparse.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbxparse.code.tex' version '4.13'
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistingsutf8.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingsutf8.code.tex' version '4.13'
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/listingsutf8.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdfescape.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistings.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '4.13'
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistingscore.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '4.13'
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '4.13'
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbexternal.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbexternal.code.tex' version '4.13' )
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbmagazine.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbmagazine.code.tex' version '4.13' )
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbvignette.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbvignette.code.tex' version '4.13'

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfadings.code.tex)))
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty:2196:
I can't find file `tcbposter.code.tex'. <to be read again    
                   \relax  l.2196 ...expand\tcbuselibrary{\tcb@optionlist}}\x
```

Comment: On an up to date (by frozen) TexLive 2017, I get no errors. Exactly what have you installed and it is the full TeXLive.

Comment: The MWE works for me. The error message seems to suggest that `tcbposter.code.tex` is missing. The question is why that file is absent if it should be on your system or why another file calls on it when it should not be on your system. Did you update any packages manually?

Comment: yes I did update it manually few weeks ago.

Comment: *Never* do your updates manually. Maybe you forgot to update one file, or it was moved or deleted or ... Maybe you should get yourself a new TeX live 2018 and use that. Only update your system via `tlmgr`. Manual updates only cause trouble.

Comment: I agree but the file `tcolorbox.doc.poster.tex` in the folder `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox`...

Comment: If the file is new and was only introduced with the manual update that could be explained if you did not run `texhash`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21726/35864

Comment: @moewe It worked. Maybe you can answer the question so that I accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a manual update to a package adds or removes files, you need to run `texhash` to make these changes known to TeX. See also [How does LaTeX find package files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21726/35864)

So after a manual update it is probably a good idea to always run `texhash` just to be sure that all changes are picked up.

---

Just to repeat my warning from the comments: **In general it is a *really* bad idea to update packages manually.** Packages should always be updated only via your TeX distribution (MikTeX's Console or TeX lives' `tlmgr`). See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864). Manual updates of complex packages or of packages with many version-sensitive dependencies (`expl3` packages like `siunitx` or `chemmacros` come to mind, the dependency between `biblatex` and Biber is a perpetual source of frustration, ...) are prone to complications.